# Hive: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: hive, parquet

I have a Parquet file (created by Drill) that I'm trying to read in Hive as an external table. The data types are copied one-to-one (i.e. INTEGER -> INT, BIGINT -> BIGINT, DOUBLE -> DOUBLE, TIMESTAMP -> TIMESTAMP, CHARACTER VARYING -> STRING). There are no complex types.

Drill has no problem querying the file it created, but Hive does not like it:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table
(
  <col> <data_type>
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '<hdfs_location>';
```

I can execute `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table` and get the correct number of rows back, but when I ask for the first row it says:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable (state=,code=0)
```

I'm not sure why it complains because I use integers and big integers, none of which I assume are stored as longs. Moreover, I would assume that an integer can be cast to a long. Is there a known workaround?

Comment: *"There are no complex types"* -- ahem, TIMESTAMP is **not** an IEEE standard like FLOAT. Moreover, Hive stores Parquet records in AVRO format so it's a three-way conversion between Hive *TIMESTAMP*, AVRO *Int64* (or is it *Long*? don't remember right now) and Java types as used by Hadoop serialization.

Comment: Erratum: it's a four-way conversion because Drill may use its own format for TIMESTAMP. I would not be surprised if either Hive or Drill used a `byte[]` to store a Unix epoch (vs. `BigInteger` in Java - which is *not* a `long`).

Comment: So, it's likely the timestamp. I'll have a look but I must say that this interoperability is putting me off Hadoop. Parquet is supposed to be the same for either Drill or Hive, am I right?

Comment: The Apache Parquet project is about *generic "containers"*, you can use Parquet to store either AVRO or ProtoBuf or Thrift binary formats. Hive supports only AVRO, with its own way of storing Date/Timestamp/Decimal/Struct/Array types inside (and some were implemented only a few months ago). Impala wants to be compatible with Hive but is lagging -- no Binary, Decimal, Date, Struct yet. Drill, well, I don't know. To be sure, you have to dig into the documentation + the JIRAs + maybe the source code. Plus, you have to check the versions of Hive and Drill involved in your setup. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, if you want a file format that is really tool-agnostic, just use CSV or SequenceFile. Remember that Parquet format is backed by Cloudera and works fine with Impala and Spark; ORC format is backed by HortonWorks and works fine with Hive & TEZ *(not supported by Impala, supported by Spark in recent releases)*; Drill is backed with MapR. That's three direct competitors fighting for corporate money. Why should they care about interoperability???

Comment: And if you want to stick to Parquet, I strongly advise you to store Timestamps either as Strings, or as Unix epochs. Actually, if you read the Hive docs carefully, you will notice that some Date/Time functions actually manipulate *Strings* and not the internal binary formats (which were introduced rather late in the project lifecycle) and others use the Epoch as a pivot for formatting/unformatting literals.

Answer (score 2):

its just because of your data. 
I was also facing same issue. 
My data in the format of int and I have created external table as String.
Give appropriate datatypes in hive create statement.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem as well. Wondering how did you discover the issue, could no t find much help otherwise. It is weird though  that even widening is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support certain data types e.g *long* - use *bigint*

Here is the 2-steps solution:

First, **drop the Table**

```
Drop  TABLE if exists <TableName>
```

Second, **recreate the Table**, this time with 'bigint' instead of 'long'

```
Create external TABLE <TableName>
(
  <col> bigint
)
Stored as Parquet
Location '<hdfs_location>';
```